# How to Run or test my Lambda function through cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

i have Created a lambda function and deployed through cloudformation.
i want the lambda function to be executed automatically after the cloudformation stack created.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to show us what you've tried and how you've set things up first. We can't help you if we can't see what you've done so far.

Comment: When you say "after the CloudFormation stack is created", would you be okay with having it execute "during" the stack creation? The benefit of this method is that, if the Lambda function returns an error, the CloudFormation stack can signal failure and trigger an automatic rollback. Also, when the stack is deleted, is can call the Lambda function again to do clean-up processing. See: [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  Roleforlambda:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - 
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
  RolePolicies: 
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties: 
      PolicyName: "root"
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - 
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "*"
            Resource: "*"
      Roles: 
        - 
          Ref: "Roleforlambda"
  lambdaFunction1:   
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Description: For getting Instance ID
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt Roleforlambda.Arn
      Code: 
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import json
          import boto3  
          import cfnresponse

          def create_key_pair(instanceid):
            ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', 'us-east-1')
            response = ec2.describe_instances()
            for reservation_data in response['Reservations']:
              for instance_data in reservation_data['Instances']:
                  for tags_data in instance_data['Tags']:
                     print(instance_data['InstanceId'])

          def lambda_handler(event, context):

            try:
              if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
                print("delete called")
                response = 'SUCCESS'
            else:
              print("create called")
              create_key_pair(instanceid)
              response = 'SUCCESS'
            cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS)    
            return response
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 200

  MyFrontEndTest: 
    Type: "Custom::Lambdatrigger"
    Properties: 
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt lambdaFunction1.Arn
      key: return x
Outputs: 
  CustomResourceAttribute1: 
    Value: !Ref MyFrontEndTest
```

Answer (score 0):

i want this lambda to be triggered and get the values of instane-id as output